# Add an exact amount of number to the column J based on column A

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table from A to E. I don't know the row count of A column so it might be 15 or 450 or any number. What I need is when I run the macros I  want it to add fixed number "7" to the column J1 till the last row of column A. I don't know how to make this. I tried many things but did not succeed. [image]

Comment: What did you try that did not succeed? Please add your code to your post. (See [mcve] and [ask] as well as the [help/on-topic].)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume that we are using Sheet1. You may change from sheet1 to:

[image]

Then try:

```
Sub test()

    Dim LR As Long
    Dim i As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("J1:J" & LR).Value = "7"
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in J1 and drag it or copy it to the end of your data row:

Formula in J1: =if(A1="","",7)

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the issue with this code block:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = y.Sheets("csv").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    y.Sheets("csv").Range("J1:J" & LastRow).Value = "7"
```

Thank you All.